# Why the frame area drawed by the pyplot is black?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My test codes are

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def run(genxy, style='point'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    #ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_xlim(0, 5.2)
    ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
    ax.hold(True)

    plt.show(False)
    plt.draw()

    background = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)

    x, y = genxy.next()
    if style == 'point':
        sincurve = ax.plot(x, y, '.')[0]
    else:
        sincurve = ax.plot(x, y)[0]

    while True:
        try:
            x, y = genxy.next()
        except StopIteration:
            break
        sincurve.set_data(x, y)
        # restore background
        fig.canvas.restore_region(background)
        # redraw just the points
        ax.draw_artist(sincurve)
        # fill in the axes rectangle
        fig.canvas.blit(ax.bbox)
        time.sleep(0.1)

    plt.close(fig)

from copy import copy
X = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)

def generate_curve(x):
    x = copy(x)
    y = np.sin(x)
    for i in range(0, len(y)):
        yield x[0:i+1], y[0:i+1]
genxy = generate_curve(X)
run(genxy, 'line')
```

And the screenshot image is

[image]

And more there is a warning printed out

> QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK. Make sure you have installed the
>   proper libraries.

My python is 2.7, my system is LMDE2(Linux Mint Debian Edition 2).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your `matplolibrc` file - this contains all the plotting defaults. On my Windows system it's here:
`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc`

You should have a line like this:
`#figure.facecolor : 0.75    # figure facecolor; 0.75 is scalar gray`

On my system if I un-comment this and change `0.75` to `0.0`, I get a black frame with your code, otherwise it's grey as it should be.

If the the line is not un-commented then I don't know where your black is coming from. Adding the line `matplotlib.rc('figure', facecolor='0.75')` immediately after your imports should hopefully fix the problem, but doesn't answer where the black has come from if not from your `matplotlibrc` file

Edit: [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=99175) link may help you  solve the GTK problem.

Comment: I tried as what you said, but the problem is as before.